# Mysql_query doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, apache

This is a serious problem for me. I just started working with AJAX and PHP but I can't even get off to a good start. Any help is greatly appreciated. As result of this code, I receive a blank page, as if the query has been performed, but there are no changes in database.

```
<?php
$user = "login";
$pass = "password";
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","qwerty","qwerty");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("database_sky", $con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO players (id, username, password) VALUES ('',$user, $pass)");

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I have no idea whats going on. Im using Apache 2.2, PHP 5, MySql 4.1

Comment: `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: If you want to get off to a good start, it would be worthwhile not starting off using deprecated API. Look into using prepared statements with `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead.  `mysql_` is deprecated and highly insecure for inexperienced users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your variables are never wrapped in single quotes (they **are meant** to be strings).

try:

```
INSERT INTO players 
   (id, username, password)
    VALUES ('','$user', '$pass')
```

Whereas your original code is evaluated like this:

```
INSERT INTO players (id, username, password) VALUES ('',John, pass)
```

this doesn't work because you need to (most likely) enter strings. You wrote `john` , not `'john'`

I'd recommend doing something like `$query = "INSERT INTO .......";`

This way you can

**a)** `echo $query;` Take the string it outputs and plug that into your PhpMyAdmin (or whatever you use as an interface to your database.

**b)** you can then do `mysql_query($query)`. This makes it easier to organize (for me, in my opinion).
:)

Comment: I'm using Navicat for Mysql, but now i see that i really messed up ^^'

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass `$con` to `mysql_query`.  The following should solve your problem:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO players (id, username, password) VALUES ('','$user', '$pass')", $con);
```

**EDIT:** Noticed another error after it was pointed out by other posters; missing single quotes around values.

Comment: Yes, updated my post to reflect this.

Comment: Also, I don't think you need to `$con` twice. Looks like the connection starts when he chooses the database.

Comment: If he had multiple connections open, specifying `$con` would be required.  Even if he doesn't, it'd be good practice at the very least.

Comment: thanks for tips i really appreciate that. ^^